# Fifth Roots of Unity

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the fifth roots of unity in the form $\cos \theta + i\sin \theta, $ where $-\pi<\theta \leq \pi$.

We know that
$$z=\cos (\frac{2\pi k}{5})+i \sin (\frac{2\pi k}{5})$$

And we substitute $k=0,1,2,3,4$ into the equation to find the fifth roots of unity.

But the solution given in the book asking to substitute $k=-2,-1,0,1,2$. Why?

Comment: Any five consecutive values of $k$ will do.

Comment: We have $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$

Comment: you're dealing with periodic functions

Comment: @SineoftheTime which mean any consecutive values of $k$ will do?

Comment: yes, see the first comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both solutions are basically correct. But you have the requirement $-\pi < \theta < \pi$ and thus $k = 3, 4$ are invalid because in that case $\dfrac{2\pi k}{5} > \pi$.

As mentioned in the comments, you always get solutions if you pick $r \in \mathbb Z$ and take $k = r, r+1, r+2, r+3, r+4$.

Comment: Let's say if $\theta< \frac{\pi}{2}$, which means cannot be $\frac{2\pi k}{5}>\frac{\pi}{2}$ ?

Comment: @Mathxx I am not sure what you mean, but if we require for example $-\frac{3\pi}{2} < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2} $, we exclude $k = 2$ and have to take $k = -3,-2,-1,0,1$.